# Как сменить или удалить пользователя в git bash

Tags: git, github, permissions

Изначально тренировался пользоваться гитом на аккаунте **DeleteMePl**, в последствии зарегистрировался нормально и склонировал (Clone with HTTPS) новый проект на ПК (Windows 7).

При попытке что-ли отправить на клонированный репозиторий получаю следующую ошибку:

> $ git push
>  remote: Permission to Пользователь/Web.git denied to
>   DeleteMePl.
>   fatal: unable to access
>   '[https://github.com/Пользователь/Web.git/](https://github.com/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/Web.git/)': The requested URL returned
>   error: 403

Github определяет меня, как старого пользователя DeleteMePl.

Когда тренировался с гитхабом, он спрашивал у меня (первый раз) логин и пароль.

**Вопрос:** где он их сохранил и как их удалить?

**Временное решение:** Пришлось открыть себе доступ через аутентификацию по ключу ssh (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key). Хотя всё работает, но меня продолжает тревожить то, что я на свой аккаунт должен получать разрешение, а не входить по логину и паролю.

**Решение описал ниже в ответе:** https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624219/226239

Comment: что-то подсказывает что вы скорее всего не верный приватный ключ используете

Comment: переустанавливал полностью git, с удалением папки, всё-равно он не запрашивает новых данных а использует старые.

Comment: а причем тут локальная копия? выже на удаленной репе пытаетесь пробиться.

Comment: Да, но ведь я при "попытке пробиться" отправляю данные о старой записи.. Значит где-то же эта запись у меня на ПК храниться?

Comment: Поишите в профиле пользователя. И вообще, ищите там в первую очередь вне зависимости от используемой программы. Сейчас большинство программ хранят специфичную для пользователя информацию там.

Comment: git config --global user.name "USERNAME NAME"

Comment: @Alex.B ему oauth access token сбросить нужно, а не имя пользователя...

Comment: К сожалению, я использую доступ по ssh - поэтому где хранится токен для http-доступа подсказать не могу.

Comment: ответ можете подсмотретть и тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed

Comment: может быть, надо всего лишь [сбросить кэш данных авторизации](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/git-credential-cache.html)? `$ git credential-cache exit`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin запрос `git credential -cache exit`, результат `usage: git credential [fill|approve|reject]`. git push не проходит: `remote: Permission to MyName/Web.git denied to DeleteMePl`

Answer (score 9):

### по поводу кэша данных при http-авторизации

возможно, вам всего лишь надо [очистить кэш данных для http-авторизации](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/git-credential-cache.html#_controlling_the_daemon):

```
$ git credential-cache exit
```

### по поводу url

> fatal: unable to access '[https://github.com/Пользователь/Web.git/](https://github.com/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/Web.git/)': The requested URL returned error: 403

это весьма похоже на *url* отдалённого хранилища. скорее всего, у вас в локальном хранилище подключено всего одно отдалённое хранилище, и, скорее всего, под псевдонимом `origin`.

посмотреть его (*url*) можно, например, такой командой:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url
```

изменить — аналогично:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url новое_значение_url
```

---

или отредактируйте любым удобным вам редактором файл `.git/config` (каталог `.git` находится в каталоге с вашим проектом), секцию `[remote "origin"]`:

```
...
[remote "origin"]
  ...
  url = это самое значение
```

Comment: Критический провал телепатии :) Он же *клонировал новый репозиторий*, то есть url у него заведомо правильный. А вот токен доступа - закешировался от другого пользователя.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, возможно, проблема в [git credential](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/git-credential-cache.html)

Comment: $ git config remote.origin.url даёт результат https://github.com/Пользователь/Web.git

Comment: Url у меня верный, я по нему зайти не могу :(

Comment: @alexanderbarakin запрос `git credential -cache exit`, результат `usage: git credential [fill|approve|reject]`. git push не проходит: `remote: Permission to MyName/Web.git denied to DeleteMePl`

Comment: @Maksym, у вас пробел лишний в команде.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin `git credential-cache exit` >> `git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @Maksym, видимо, программа git у вас [старее 1.7.9](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/4827341) (или как-то по-особому скомпилирована). попробуйте явно указать нужное имя пользователя в url: `https://имя@github.com/...`. если и это не поможет, настоятельно рекомендую переходить к более полноценному способу авторизации — по ключу (и, соответственно, по протоколу ssh, а не http).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin К сожалению пришлось перейти к аутенификации через ssh, меня, правда, смущает, что я на свой акк захожу через permission, а не по логину и паролю, как было раньше.

Comment: Интересная альтернатива `git remote set-url`. :)

Comment: @Maksym авторизация через ssh надёжнее, чем логин и пароль. Грубо говоря, ключ — это тоже пароль, только в нём очень, очень много символов.

Answer (score 9):

*Решение найдено:*
Необходимо зайти в:
Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей и семейная безопасность\Диспетчер учетных данных
в разделе: "**общие учетные данные**" удалить учётку для git. Выглядит она так: `git:https://github.com`
При следующем взаимодействии в консоле, git попросит ввести логин и пароль в отдельном окне авторизации.

Answer (score 6):

В Windows 10:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

Выбрать Windows Credential

Удалить или изменить соответствующий git:http ...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Авторизация сбрасывается одной командой в терминале

```
echo "url=https://github.com" | git credential reject
```

Это проще, чем искать диспетчер учетных данных в панели управления.