# Git после смены репозитория на github

Tags: git, github, git-push

Когда я пытаюсь запушить на github свой проект из android studio. Он мне выдает ошибку доступа.

> remote: Permission to AndromedaMobileDevelopment/Shimmer.git denied to
>   ExodusMob
>   ile. fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/AndromedaMobileDevelopment/Shimmer.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

На самом деле правда, я был раньше привязан к аккаунту exodusmobile. Как теперь сменить?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585435/178576 , но лучше, конечно, использовать ssh, а не http.