# Переопределение локального пользователя

Tags: windows, git, github

Как переопределить в гит репозитории локального юзера? Прописываю новые user.name и user.email, но гит все равно пытается запушить по глобальным настройкам.

Ошибка после `git push origin master`

```
remote: Permission to имя_локальное/репозиторий.git denied to имя_глобальное.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/имя_локальное/репозиторий.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Обновление 1.
В `git log` автором коммитов записан локально определенный юзер (имя и емайл).
Но при пуше он видимо все равно, обращается к глобальным настройкам (предположение). Что сделать, чтоб пуш прошел?

Comment: Автор коммитов это одно, пользователь под которым вы авторизуетесь — совсем другое.

Comment: @NickVolynkin т.е. мне надо поменять авторизацию в системе гит? это не через конфиг делается?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585435/178576

Answer (score 2):

Документация GitHub говорит о том, что такая ошибка связана с Deploy ключом. Deploy key – это SSH-ключ.

Ввиду разных пользователей на удалённом репозитории и на локальном, можно установить соединение через открытый ключ.

Поэтому нужно не в этом файле копаться:

```
~/.gitconfig
```

Конкретнее нужен SSH-ключ, который должен быть на Вашей локальной машине и этот же ключ должен быть добавлен в ключи доступа желаемого удалённого репозитория.

**Инструкция ниже для *nix машин.**

Для начала нужно проверить наличие существующих открытых ключей. Чтобы проверить наличие открытого SSH-ключа, нужно прописать в терминале:

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
```

По умолчанию, названия открытых ключей отображаются следующим образом:

```
id_dsa.pub
id_ecdsa.pub
id_ed25519.pub
id_rsa.pub
```

Если нет такого ключа или по каким-то причинам не хочется использовать существующие, то можно сгенерировать новый публичный SSH-ключ:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "твоя_почта@почтовый_поддомен.домен"
```

После команды выше будет создан новый SSH-ключ, который будет сопровождаться почтой, как меткой (label).

В Терминале выведется следующее:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

Нажав Enter, ключ будет создан в директории по умолчанию.
Выведутся строки ниже, где нужно будет ввести пароль-фразу и повторить её.

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Напиши фразу]
Enter same passphrase again: [Напиши фразу]
```

После сгенерированного ключа, нужно этот ключ добавить в SSH-agent. Для начала нужно убедиться в том, что SSH-agent активирован:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Должно вывести примерно следующее:

```
Agent pid 39591
```

После, остаётся добавить SSH-ключ в SSH-агент:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Теперь, давайте добавим ключ в ключи доступа на удалённом репозитории. Сначала, добавим SSH-ключ в буфер обмена:

```
$ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Делаем следующее:

1. Открываем GitHub в браузере и авторизовываемся
2. Заходим в Settings
3. Открываем раздел SSH and GPG keys
4. Нажимаем New SSH key
5. Вставляем из буфера обмена в раздел Key данные
6. Заполняем Title
7. Добавляем ключ и подтверждаем добавление, введя пароль от аккаунта.

**Profit.** У вас должна установиться связь между локальной машиной и удалённым репозиторием через SSH-ключ. Решение основано на информации, которое предлагает техподдержка GitHub.

Comment: Это что то не то, я пытаюсь переопределить глобального пользователя на локального, чтоб от него в истории были коммиты. У меня windows и https.