# git как вернуть запрос пароля?

Tags: git, пароль

Имя пользователя / пароль запрашивались ровно один раз - при `git clone`, больше ни разу не запрашивались ни при `pull`, ни при `push`.

Как сделать, чтобы пароль запрашивался каждый раз?

Работаю с git в windows 7 через обычную командную строку.

Comment: А он какой пароль у вас просит? От SSH-ключа или от учётной записи на гитхабе?

Comment: Тот же вопрос другими словами: URL для `git clone` начинался с `http` или с `git@`?

Comment: Не просит ни какой, а хочу, чтобы спрашивал от учётной записи на gitlab.com

Comment: URL начинался с https

Comment: @NickVolynkin, похоже на это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585421/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ага, очень похоже.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin инфа полезная, спасибо, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Да, я могу удалить свою учётную запись в диспетчере учётных данных, но при следующем обращении к серверу я введу логин/пароль и он опять будет запомнен.

Comment: тогда используйте «нормальную» аутентификацию — по ключу. который можно зашифровать паролем. т.е., при каждом обращении к ключу (если он не сохранён в кэше ssh-agent-а или что у вас там в *ms/windows* используется для кэширования ssh-ключей) будет запрашиваться пароль для его расшифровки.

Answer (score 2):

А вот и ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-to-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows

Запускаем командную строку от имени администратора, там выполняем команду `git config --system --unset credential.helper`

Опционально, можно зайти в Панель управления->Учётные записи->Диспетчер учётных данных и удалить свою git учётку.

Comment: Скажите, а почему вам необходимо каждый раз вводить логин и пароль? Требования безопасности на работе? Может быть, вам бы подошел SSH-ключ с паролем.

Comment: @NickVolynkin клонировал репозиторий и временно работал с ним на чужом компьютере