# Как удалить сохранённый пароль из Git

Tags: git

Например у меня есть аккаунт на bitbucket.org. В первый раз когда я делаю git push я ввожу логин и пароль, он его запоминает. Как мне его сбросить?

Comment: Через консоль/терминал работаете с гитом или через IDE? Какая операционная система?

Comment: Через консоль, Windows 10

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сменить или удалить пользователя в git bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585421/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-git-bash)

Comment: В Git Bash: `echo url=https://bitbucket.org|git credential reject`

Comment: Чем вы пользуетесь, Windows? Соединяетесь через https или ssh?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте просто сбросить данные о пользователе и при следующем вызове `git push` у вас запросит новые данные:

```
git config --global --unset user.password
```

Comment: нет, это не работает

Comment: @JonnyManowar возможно настройка у вас не глобальная, а для проекта, попробуйте убрать `--global` со строки.

Comment: Тоже не работает

Comment: Это в `git credential` (или как его там) запоминается — отдельная сущность.