# Проблема со сменой github аккаунта

Tags: git, github

У меня есть аккаунт на github'e, которым я пользовался когда был совсем новичком там хранятся старые репозитории, они можно сказать черновые. Я не хочу удалять их, но так же я не хочу пушить на него готовые не черновые работы, поэтому я обзавелся еще одним аккаунтом.

Но при пуше на него первой же работы я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что мне просто запрещено пушить на него. Ошибка

> The requested URL returned error: 403.

Я не помню что при работе с первым аккаунтом я как-то инициализировал его в git'e (Что странно, ведь нельзя же залить код на чужой аккаунт). В глобальном config файле нету настроек, которые задавали бы пароль, чтобы его можно было сменить на пароль текущего аккаунта, только почта и имя их я поменял, но как понял они нужны чтобы отображаться в log'ах.

В общем явного решения проблемы в интернете я не нашел. Если вы знаете как решить эту проблему помогите! Я потерял уже 2 дня на решение проблемы.

Comment: Или я вас не так понял, или вам просто надо добавить пользователей которые могут пушить на репозитории...

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585421/178576)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение проблемы при двух аккаунтах на github'e. Итак если у вас два или более аккаунтов на github'e, и при пуше на один из репозиториев вам отвечает консоль 403 ошибкой(нет доступа), то решением будет следующий метод.

Прописываете в консоли такой код:

```
 git config --global credential.github.com.interactive always
```

Потом снова пушим:

```
 git push -u <nameRepo> <nameBranch>
```

Должно появится окно в котором вы авторизовываетесь в своем github аккаунте.

ПРОФИТ!

Статья:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/Configuration.md