# git submodule update fatal authentication

Tags: git, cmd, git-submodule

В репозитории ядро подклчается как сабмодуль. Первый раз после команды

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

появилось окно, с требованием ввести для credentials "log and pass", я вел не те данные и теперь постоянно ошибка

> Cloning into 'C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Projects/gormost-monorepo/packages/core'...
>   fatal: Authentication failed for

Перезагружал комп, пробовал вводить команду в cmd, gitbash, storm , требования ввести снова данные не появляются. Как решить проблему?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager тут удаляем пользоательские данные и все заработает

Comment: [фактически дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585421/178576)