# git clone unauthorized

Tags: linux, git, bash

Помогите пж((  Ошиблась при первой попытке в логине чтобы склонировать репо , теперь больше не предлагает ввести((( ssh-keygen добавила

```
$ git clone https://git.jetbrains.space/freeitblr/photostorage/photostorage.git
Cloning into 'photostorage'...
remote: Unauthorized LoginAndPassword(Nastya/***): User not found
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.jetbrains.space/freeitblr/photostorage/photostorage.git/'
```

Как мне получить вторую попытку?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585435/178576

Answer (score -1):

> Как мне получить вторую попытку?

Может быть поможет опция:

```
-o <name>, --origin <name>
       Instead of using the remote name origin to keep track of the upstream repository, use <name>.
```