# Появляется ошибка при вводе git push -u Error: failed to push some refs to...?

Tags: git, github, контроль-версий

На данный момент я учусь сотрудничать, вносить свой вклад в другие репозитории.

Допустим существует репозиторий **VvDone/Week3Test**, я хочу внести вклад в этот проект и добавить файл с именем ***"newFile.js"*** . Я нажимаю **Fork**, теперь на моем аккаунте есть копия этого репозитория **Ralbf/Week3Test**.

Я клонирую репозиторий  **Ralbf/Week3Test** к себе на компьютер.

Добавляю новую ветку с именем ***"AddNewFile"*** командой ***git checkout -b AddNewFile***

Теперь я добавляю новый файл ***newFile.js***.

Индексирую, делаю коммит:

***git add newFile.js.***

***git commit -m "Add newFile.js"***

Теперь я хочу отправить изменения в репозиторий.
Я ввожу команду:
***git push --set-upstream origin AddNewFile.***

Но у меня не получается, потому что появляется ошибка

[image]

Прочитал в интернете что нужно ввести ***git pull***. Вот вывод при вводе git pull

[image]
Пытаюсь ввести команды, которые предлагает GIT

**1. git pull origin AddNewFile**

[image]
**2. git branch --set-upstream-to origin/AddNewFile AddNewFile.**
[image]

Выручайте)

Comment: просто ``git push``?

Comment: @Эникейщик 
**$ git push**

_fatal: The current branch AddNewFile has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin AddNewFile_

Comment: ``git config --list`` user.name и user.email есть? ну и все остальные данные там верные?

Comment: я бы ещё посмотрел через `git branch -a` есть ли в удаленных ветках нужная. Может ее кто то удалил.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, вы правы. Я поменял аккаунт, но забыл изменить данные в config user.name и user.email. Казалось бы, что ошибка после этого должна исчезнуть, но она по прежнему появляется( Странно

Comment: @KoVadim, вот такие ветки выводит с командой `git branch -a`
* AddNewFile
  main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main

Comment: вот вот - в удаленном репозитории нет привязанной ветки. `--set-upstream` должно было создать эту ветку в удаленном репозитории, но... а через сайт github можете создавать ветки?

Comment: @KoVadim Через сайт github ветки создавать могу.

Comment: А свой ключик ssh на GitHub добавили? Когда сделаете, поверьте в консоли вот такой командой `ssh -T git@github.com`. должно распечатать имя на гитхабе и сказать ок. Если нет - разбирайтесь с ssh ключами и правами

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за помощь. Проблема действительно была в авторизации. Я работал на одном аккаунте GitHub, затем пересел на другой. Старые данные остались в кэше Windows из-за чего появлялась ошибка с правами. Помогло удаление данных из кэша Windows:
Необходимо зайти в:
Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей и семейная безопасность\Диспетчер учетных данных
в разделе: "общие учетные данные" удалить учётку для git. Выглядит она так: git:https://github.com
При следующем взаимодействии в консоле, git попросит ввести логин и пароль в отдельном окне авторизации.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Я работал на одном аккаунте GitHub, затем пересел на другой. Старые данные остались в кэше Windows из-за чего появлялась ошибка с правами. Помогло удаление данных из кэша Windows: [Как изменить/удалить данные пользователя в GIT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585421/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2-git-bash)

***Необходимо зайти в:***

Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей и семейная безопасность\Диспетчер учетных данных

в разделе: "Учетные данные Windows" удалить учётку для git. Выглядит она так:

`git:https://github.com`

После команды `git push` потребуется снова авторизоваться уже с новыми правами.